# How to set a UITextField.text to a NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsdate

I'm connecting to an API and when I get data back for dates it looks like this:

```
2016-07-05T21:39:17.696Z
```

How can I set a uitextfield.text to that date so it looks like a normal date (ie. 07/05/2016 or something similar)?

The tricky part is the NSDate is returned as a string from the API so it's not in the NSDate format to begin with.

Comment: look into nsdateformatter

Answer (score 1):

A text field is only for editing freeform text, not dates.  You can go one of two routes.  If you intend for the user to be able to edit a date, then use a `UIDatePicker` to provide an interface specifically for editing dates.  If you just want freeform text back, then you can convert a date to a string with `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
let yourDate = NSDate()
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle
self.textfield.text = formatter.stringFromDate(yourDate)
```